# Unity Localization Tables - How to simply add details to localized string in text

Tags: unity, localization

I recently added localization for my UI. Now I am working on the save menu, where it should display the slot number and then the date of the last save.

Like so:
[image: desired result]

However it doesn't always work, sometimes the menu looks like this:

[image: broken menu]

I tried debugging the script and the formatting function is always called correctly and returns the desired string, but that somehow gets lost and wont show in the actual UI.

I tried following the Unity Dynamic String documentation, but I can't really see how the want me to implement it. I would be glad for some hints or examples how to add details to localized strings.

Each save slot is a copy of the slot prefab, and they all run this script:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Globalization;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Localization;

/// <summary>
/// Gathers information about the assigned save slot (indicated by slotNumber) and displays a string
/// on the assigned gameobjects TextBox.
/// Registers Attached GOs buttons for saving and loading correct slot.
/// Stores time of last save for assigned slot
/// </summary>
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SaveSlotUIBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    // assigned in inspector
    public int slotNumber;
    bool hasSave = false;

    public LocalizedString slotTextLocalized;
    TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI slotText;
    Button saveBtn;
    Button loadBtn;

    string dateFormat;
    string timeFormat;

    private SaveFileHandler.SaveFileInfo info;


    private void Awake()
    {
        //get datetime formatting for region of current user
        dateFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString();
        timeFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern.ToString();

        info = SaveFileHandler.CheckFileAndGetInfo(slotNumber);
        if (!info.validSaveFile)
        {
            Debug.Log($"SaveFile for slot {slotNumber} is missing or corrupted!");
            hasSave = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log($"SaveFile for slot {slotNumber} found: {info.dateTime.ToString(dateFormat + timeFormat)}");
            hasSave = true;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        slotTextLocalized.RefreshString();

        // register button events with functions, dont have to do it in inspector for every prefab instance
        saveBtn.onClick.AddListener(OnSave);
        loadBtn.onClick.AddListener(OnLoad);

        UpdateButtons();

    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Register a ChangeHandler. This is called whenever the string needs to be updated.
    /// </summary>
    void OnEnable()
    {
        slotTextLocalized.StringChanged += UpdateString;
    }
    
    void OnDisable()
    {
        slotTextLocalized.StringChanged -= UpdateString;
    }
    
    void UpdateString(string s)
    {
        var details = BuildDisplayString();
        var newText = string.Format(s, details);
        Debug.Log($"Set text for Slot {slotNumber}: {newText}");
        slotText.text = newText;
    }

    // on save button press
    public void OnSave()
    {
        // save data
        SaveFileHandler.Save(slotNumber);
        info.dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        info.validSaveFile = true;
        hasSave = true;
        slotTextLocalized.RefreshString();
        // enable load button if it wasnt
        UpdateButtons();
    }
    
    string BuildDisplayString()
    {
        // check if slot has savefile and display its date and time
        if (hasSave)
        {
            // build datetime string from file metadata
            return info.dateTime.ToString($"{slotNumber}\n{dateFormat}\n{timeFormat}");
        }
        else
        {
            // if slot is empty, replace "Empty with correct word"
            return $"{slotNumber}\nEmpty";
        }
    }

    // on load button press
    public void OnLoad()
    {
        if (hasSave && SaveFileHandler.CheckSaveFileExists(slotNumber))
        {
            SaveFileHandler.Load(slotNumber);
            loadBtn.interactable = false;
        }
    }

    void UpdateButtons()
    {
        // disable save button if menu is opened from title screen
        if (SceneController.IsMainMenu)
        {
            saveBtn.interactable = false;
        }
        // disable load btn if no save file is present
        loadBtn.interactable = hasSave;
    }

}
```

The print statement to the update function shows exactly what I want, however, the UI does not update correctly:
[image]

The localization table section for the menu:

[image: loc table]

GameObject Script component:
[image]

Text box localizer:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: By just reading your code, it seems your OnEnabled is sometimes not called. How do you open/ close/ navigate to that menu? And you could try to add the listener in Awake and remove the OnEnable/ Disable to test if that is causing the problem. And last, wouldnt it be better to assign the buttons directly over the editor compared to use `gameObject.transform.Find("SaveBtn")`, you can as well assign the method calls there

Comment: My menu is a scene which is loaded as overlay and I switch between settings and saving submenus by enabling/ disabling the respective parent GOs. Putting the event listener in Awake did not work. I assigned the buttons in the inspector now.

Comment: @Zibelas I added a log statement to the update function and a screenshot of the log with the broken ui.

Comment: If you solved your problem, post your solution as an Answer below, not as an edit to the question. You can then later mark that answer "Accepted" if you're satisfied with how it solves your problem.

Comment: @DMGregory I know, but I didn't solve the underlying problem, I just made a hacky workaround.
I wasn't sure if that would qualify as answer.

Comment: Last small check, since it is working with Instantiating, can you check if the `ExecuteInEditMode` is causing your problems? Simply remove it